# Minimize squared error of linear function

Tags: optimization, least-squares, regression, quadratic-programming

Let $M$ be a $m \times n$ matrix, $x$ a $n$-vector, $y$ a $m$-vector, and $\|\cdot\|_2$ represent the $L_2$ norm (i.e., Euclidean norm).  Given $M,y$, the goal is to find $x$ that minimizes the expression

$$\Psi(x) = \|x\|^2 + \|Mx-y\|^2.$$

Is there a closed-form expression for the optimal $x$?  Without the $\|x\|^2$ term, this would be an instance of ordinary least squares linear regression and there would be a nice solution, but I'm not sure happens with this additional term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is still a linear least squares problem.  You can write $\Psi(x)$ as

$\Psi(x)=\| Hx - g \|_{2}^{2}$

where

$H=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
I \\
M
\end{array}
\right]
$

and

$g=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
y 
\end{array}
\right]$.

Using the normal equations,

$x=(H^{T}H)^{-1}H^{T}g=(M^{T}M+I)^{-1} M^{T}y$.